# Salesforce Apex: Date String to Date Issue in Dynamic Query

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

This is probably an easy one. Im having issues getting the proper date format from a date string to use in a dynamic SOQL statement's where clause. Ive tried variations of the date functions but am still not able to figure out the correct format. The custom object field is of type Date. All suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

```
public string startDate {get;set;}
public string endDate {get;set;}

public void mymethod(){

   string SOQLString = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Time__c WHERE Closed__c = true';

   if(startDate != null && endDate != null && startDate.length() > 0 && endDate.length() > 0)
   {
      Date sd = Date.Parse(startDate);
      Date ed = Date.Parse(endDate);

      SOQLString = SOQLString + ' and Date_Incurred__c >= ' + sd + ' and Date_Incurred__c <= ' + ed;
      //SOQLString = SOQLString + ' and Date_Incurred__c >= \'' + sdt + '\' and Date_Incurred__c <= \'' + edt + '\'';
}

   List<Time__c> times = Database.Query(SOQLString);
   ...
```

OUTPUT of SOQLString

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Time__c WHERE Closed__c = true and Date_Incurred__c >= 2013-09-27 00:00:00 and Date_Incurred__c <= 2013-09-02 00:00:00
```

ERROR

```
System.QueryException: line 1:1082 no viable alternative at character ' '
```

Comment: Figured out a solution.  I used the parseDate function from this [article](http://208.74.204.95/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Convert-String-to-Date-Exception-in-US-locale-when-DateString/m-p/667792) to convert the string to a date.  Then I modified my dynamic SOQLString value to the following:  `SOQLString = SOQLString + ' and Date_Incurred__c >= :sd and Date_Incurred__c <= :ed';`

Answer (score 0):

We can use the variable inside the quotation with colon. So it will replace the variable value automatically.

**Example :**

```
SOQLString + ' and Date_Incurred__c >= :sd'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use it in a Dynamic Query (Database.query()) You can use this piece of code:

```java
if (value == null) {
    value = 'null';
} else if (value instanceof Date) {
    Date dateValue = (Date) value;
    String monthString = String.valueof(dateValue.month());
    monthString = dateValue.month() < 10 ? '0' + monthString : monthString;
    String dayString = String.valueof(dateValue.day());
    dayString = dateValue.day() < 10 ? '0' + dayString : dayString;
    value = dateValue.year() + '-' + monthString + '-' + dayString;
}
```

Where value is a Date variable